# What happened to the USSR hospital at Khmelnitsky?

Tags: historical-context, belarusian-language, svetlana-alexievich, zinky-boys

An interview with a major in *Zinky Boys* (day 2, track 8 in the audiobook) referred to a hospital of some kind in Khmelnitsky for long-term casualties who couldn't or wouldn't go home for various reasons. He also mentioned having received a recent letter from someone who was there.

This book was written not so long after the end of the war (and prior to the fall of the Soviet Union), so it is perhaps unsurprising that it still existed. However, obviously the Soviet Union fell several years later. What became of this location and the people who were staying there?

**Note:** The original version of this question got the publication date wrong, which invalidated the original version of this question.